# how to change color and name of button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

```css
.enc-btn {
  background-color: #02bc15;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label>Encounter Status:</label>
<button class="btn px-3 py-1 enc-btn">Opened</button>
```

I want the button to be changed to
`#ff3030` when clicked.

So I want to change the color of the button to change to that color under the button css after it has been clicked.
I need a more permanent solution than :focus
And I also want the "opened" to change to "closed".

Comment: Depending on the use case, you can use the pseudo class `:focus` (see answer below) or `:active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using DOM.

JavaScript code example:

```js
function btnclick(event) {
  event.target.textContent = !event.target.classList.contains('opened') ? 'Closed' : 'Opened'
  event.target.classList.toggle('opened')
}

// Adding individual listeners is inefficient, this would more correctly be done with event delegation
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  for(let button of document.getElementsByClassName('enc-btn'))
    button.addEventListener('click', btnclick);
})
```

```css
.enc-btn {
  background-color: #02bc15;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}

.opened {
  background-color: #ff3030
}
```

```html
<label>Encounter Status:</label>
<button class="btn px-3 py-1 enc-btn">Opened</button>
<button class="btn px-3 py-1 enc-btn">Opened</button>
```

```
const button = document.querySelector('.btn');
button.addEventListener('click', btnclick); 
function btnclick() {
  button.style.backgroundColor = '#ff3030';
}
```

Comment: Can the queryselector be more specific than .btn because I wouldnt want any other button to have the same effect. Also please read the question again I added a new need

Comment: You can add an id to the button and then use queryselector or getelementbyid to select that particular button. As for your new question to change text, you can try button.innerHTML

Comment: @Leon you can assign id="myBtn" to button and use #myBtn in querySelector

Comment: @SagunGautam adding an `id` would only work for a single instance of this control.  It's implied by the OP that it there needs to be multiple instances of the control on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) psuedo-class.

```css
.enc-btn {
  background-color: #02bc15;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}

button.enc-btn:focus {
  background-color: #ff3030;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label>Encounter Status:</label>
<button class="btn px-3 py-1 enc-btn">Opened</button>
```

Edit ~ solution with js.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.innerHTML = 'Opened';

// Change button text on click
btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
  const initialText = 'Opened';

  btn.innerHTML = `Closed`;
});

// change color 
btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
  btn.style.backgroundColor = '#ff3030';
  btn.style.color = 'white';
});
```

```css
.enc-btn {
  background-color: #02bc15;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label>Encounter Status:</label>
<button class="btn px-3 py-1 enc-btn" id="btn"></button>
```

Comment: They posted that after my solution was posted. All they wanted initially was to change the color. If you look, you’ll notice that there are two solutions which handles the new “requirements”.

Comment: Sorry, that's not very fair

Answer (score 0):

A couple easy ways to do this would be to either use the jQuery addClass function or css function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".enc-btn").click(function(){
     $(".enc-btn").css("color", "#ff3030");
     $(".enc-btn").addClass("new-color");
  });
});

.enc-btn {
  background-color: #02bc15;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}

.new-color {
  color: #ff3030;
}
```

I've gone ahead and thrown it in a fiddle you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/BrianChenoweth/ch6v8og7/8/

Comment: Please check the question again. i added a new need!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method in JavaScript

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#myBtn");

myBtn.addEventListener("click" , () => {
  
  btn.style.backgroundColor = '#ff3030';

})
```

```css
.enc-btn {
  background-color: #02bc15;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label>Encounter Status:</label>
<button id="myBtn" class="btn px-3 py-1 enc-btn">Opened</button>
```